# C# SQL Connection.Open()

Tags: c#, sql

I wonder if anyone can help me, I'm trying to Connect to an SQL database and pass some data to it, problem is, each time I try to open a connection the application "hangs" if you will at the `conn.Open();`command and I don't know why, At first I thought it was a problem with my code, but even if I download some source code it still does the same, can anyone explain to me why this happens ? Here is the code that gives the problem, I haven't coded the rest yet,

```
private void Frm_Insert_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        Conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:/Test/Test.mdf; Integrated Security = True;Connect Timeout = 30;";
        try
        {
            Conn.Open();//It stops here, any advice ?
            MessageBox.Show("Accepted");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());

        }
    }   
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testDataSet.UserNames' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.userNamesTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDataSet.UserNames);

}
```

If I wait long enough I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>       The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>       (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I'm running on a local host.

Comment: What sql server version?

Comment: Is it not `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` (backward instead of forward -slash)?

Comment: You could try using `.` or `127.0.0.1` in place of `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: It's not hanging. You have a connect timeout of 30. That's why waiting long enough gives you the error.

Comment: If it still doesn't work with backwards also open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and check the instance name that appears in the login window and use the instance name in the c# application.

Comment: Open the VS developer command prompt. Type: `sqllocaldb info`. Do you have an instance by that name?

Comment: I found something else that worked I used Conn.ConnectionString = DataTest.Properties.Settings.Default.TestConnectionString; , It fixed the problem but whats the draw back by using this command instead ?